# configuring git not to change the linendings

Tags: git

I have a git repository, in which I want to have git leave the line endings of the files as it is, since the sw tool I use writes certain files with windows style and certain with linux style, regardless of the operating system the tool is running on.
I don't want this definition to be global to all my repositories.
I want it to be inside the repository, so that all the users will share the same crlf behaviour
I saw that in .gitattributes, I can choose only from the 3 options:
lf
crlf
binary (which is an alias to -merge -diff)

with lf/crlf, I need to specify file by file what is its crlf style, which is tedious.
with binary, all files are as is, but when I use it, I see that tortoisegit, doesn't display how many lines has changed, since it treats it as binary.
I assume I will also loose the option to merge files that are defined as binary.
What I really want is just to define that git checks in and out as it is, without defining the files as binaries,
and I want it to be done within the .gitattributes file
is this posssible?

Answer (score 0):

To mark some particular file as "do not touch line endings" (when line ending messing-about is otherwise enabled), simply list the file as `-text` in the appropriate `.gitattributes` entry.  For instance:

```
precious.file   -text
```

prevents Git from messing with any file whose name component is `precious.file` (here or in any subdirectory).

Note that `binary` is effectively a macro attribute that means *both* `-text` *and* `-diff` (plus `-merge` as well); you want *only* `-text`.